# How to display Selected option value Selected in option tag in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have Select Option Tag such as

```
 <select class="form-control" name="some_name" id="some_name">
            {% for newdata in data %}
                  <option value="{{newdata.id}}" {% if "newdata.id==demodata.id" %} selected  {% endif  %}>{{newdata.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
 
   </select>
```

i am Displying option value dynamically using "data" variable. "demodata" is another variable containing values.

Now i want to make selected option selected when "newdata.id==demodata.id" this condition is true.However below code is not working

```
<option value="{{newdata.id}}" {% if "newdata.id==demodata.id" %} selected  {% endif  %}>{{newdata.name}}</option>
```

i don't Know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes and it should work

```
{% if newdata.id == demodata.id %}
```

Comment: `<select id="category" class="ui search dropdown">`
`<option value="">Category</option>`
`{% for category in categories %}`
`<option value="{{ category.name }}"{% if explore_blog.category == category %}` `selected {% endif %}>{{ category.name }}</option>`
`{% endfor %}`
`</select>`

This is a working example, maybe using this as a reference may help you also check if you are sending instance for demodata or queryset. Good Luck